# Fluent validation does not validate fields of objects in an array

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have the following validator. It works as supposed to on the fields in the root level. However, it seems that there's no validation on the fields of the objects in the array.

```
public class ReporterValidator : AbstractValidator<Reporter>
{
  public ReporterValidator()
  {
    RuleFor(a => a.Name).Length(5, 10);
    RuleForEach(a => a.Fields).ChildRules(a =>
    {
      a.RuleFor(b => b.Key).Length(4, 8);
      a.RuleFor(b => b.Retention).InclusiveBetween(2, 7);
    });
  }
}
```

The classes are declared as follows.

```
public class Reporter
{
  public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
  public Field[] Fields { get; set; } = Array.Empty<Field>();

  public class Field
  {
    public string Key { get; set; } = default!;
    public int Retention { get; set; } = default!;
  }
}
```

What could I be missing?

The source I'm following is [here](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/collections.html#collections-of-complex-types). My understanding is that I don't need to add separate validator class for the type stored in the array nor, by extension, register that explicitly other than:

```
services.AddScoped<IValidator<Reporter>, ReporterValidator>();
```

Comment: The great thing about fluent validation is: it has excellent support for unit testing the validators. I think the quickest way to investigate would be to set up a decent set of validation tests.

Comment: @Fildor I'm not sure how to apply the advice in my case. It seems that the validator reacts to the name being too long but not retention too long. I sense I'm missing something fairly simple.

Comment: I assume the difference between the names of classes `Reporter` and `ReporterInValidator` and the registration clause `services.AddScoped<IValidator<ReporterI>, ReporterValidator>();` is just an artifact of constructing the example?

Comment: One thing that occurs to me: are you sure that, in your tests, the Fields property is actually populated? If it were indeed an empty array of `Field` then "not flagging the properties" is exactly what I would expect.

Comment: @AnnL. Your assumption is perfectly correct. The actual type is `ReporterInput` but it seems superfluous to keep the longer version. Thanks for the remark - sloppiness corrected now.

Comment: @AnnL. As for your question - yes, the array is actually populated and has invalid values in it. There's no requirement for the reporter to have an array but in case it does, then the objects in it mustn't violate the conditions. I've followed the object from Postman down to the DB and the violating values are present and stored.

Comment: @AnnL. I'll take you latest comment that you see no obvious mistake and you'd expect it to work. Is that correct? Is there a super-duper dummy rule that always fails? To assert that the fields actually are subject to validation, that is. The only "tricky" thing I can imagine is that the type of the array is an inner class declared inside the reporter type. But that should hardly matter, shouldn it?

Comment: @AnnL. I've found the issue. Apparently, someone decided to shave the *Program.cs* file and removed `AddFluentValidationAutoValidation()` (since *"we already have `AddScoped<IValidator<T>, TV>()` so it's not needed"*). And it was done **after** I checked the fields on the root level but **prior to** me checking the array level values. Once I started to revise all my assumptions, I discovered that thing. Someone needs to pick the music. For the funeral. Because I'm going to kill them.   :)

Comment: Congratulations!  And, man oh man, is that kind of thing MADDENING!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Not a big fan of answering my own question but I'll do it this time.*

The issue was that the call to register the validation facility (i.e. `AddFluentValidationAutoValidation()`) was removed (with a sorely poor timing between my tests).

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
  IServiceCollection services = builder.Services;
  ...
  services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();
  ...
}
```

Once the last statement in the sample above is present, the validation works - both for root objects and for array objects. As expected...